# Bezier curve as Instance in geometry nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I have a grid with Bezier segment as instance like below: [image]

Now, how to "make" the instances to bend, close to point A and converge close to point B?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this task (among others) as follows:

[image]

As you can see, here I simply instantiate curves, which consist of two points, convert them after instantiation into a *Bezier curve*, and then move the handle positions.

I do this here because all parameters of a curve are lost by the node `Realize Instances`. This is because the curve is resampled. However, for further processing of the curves after the instantiation it is necessary to realize them.

With this setup you can also define the points to which the handles are to be directed, arbitrarily on all axes. Instead of the *Vector* input nodes you can also use the position of another object with `Object Info`.

Another example would be to bend the curve first and then instantiate it. But this would make all curves look the same.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thank you for a quick help.

Comment: @mptaurus You are welcome!